# Adobe Flash Professional CS5 edit

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, swfobject, fla

I am new to Flash and I need to edit some files that are used in a flash project. The files I need to edit are in actionscript. What is the relation to the file types .as(actionscript), .fla (flash?), and .swf   Also, do I need to recompile after any changes I make to an actionscript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely,  the `.fla` file is the main project file (what ties everything together).   The `.swf` files are likely the final output from said project file.   The `.as` files are code files that are likely attached to various items in the `.fla` file.

Here is an example:

You create a project in FlashPro/AdobeAnimate,  you import some graphics, animate them on a timeline, and then want to add some code to those graphics to make them do something dynamic, so you create a class file (.as) and write some code, then link that class file to a timeline or object in FlashPro.  When you are all done, you publish your application.  This creates a .swf file which is then used on the web (legacy) or loaded by another application (Adobe Air, Visual Studio etc.).

Now, `.swf` files can also be used by other `.swf` files when a program runs.  So some assets like graphics (.png, gif, jpeg, .swf) could be used by the application at run-time.   The `.fla` & the `.as` file(s) though are only used for authoring and are not needed for running the published application.

You DO need to re-publish your .fla after any changes to an Actionscript (.as) file - this will generate a new .swf file.